# Changes in relative position of text not carrying over to mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css-position, android-relativelayout

I need to try and move a section of text over by about 3 percent. Unfortunately, this change will not actually show up on mobile devices no matter what I do. Is the problem with my code, or is there a problem with androids in relative positioning?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            posit{
            position:relative;
            left:25%;
            max-width:500 px;
            }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="rightcol">
        <p><strong>????????</strong></p>
        <p>??????????</p>
        <p><strong>???????????</strong></p>
        <p>???????????? </p>
        <p>????????????? <a href="/??????.htm">?????????</a>.</p>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <div id="centercol">
        <h1>??????????</h1>
        <p><strong>????????</strong></p>
        <p>????????</p>
        <p><strong>????????????</strong></p>
        <p>?????????</p>
        <p><strong>??????</strong></p>
        <posit>
        <p>??????????????</p>
        </posit>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the positioning and the max-width of the posit object, maybe something like:

```
posit{
position : relative;
left: 25%;
}
.some-class{
max-width: 500px;
}
```